# Justify menu in Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't justify menu in bootstrap 3 using regular `text-align:justify` and `display: inline-block`, but everything is ok on the sites without bootstrap.

1. The site without bootstrap (http://shop.staceydogs.ru). The menu have this structure:

   ```
   .sd-menu
   — ul
   — — li
   — — li
   ...
   — — li
   — — ul:after
   ```

And this style:

```
.sd-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.sd-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: justify;
}
.sd-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sd-menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And everything works great!

1. The site with bootstrap (http://dogs.fuksman.ru). The menu have this structure:

   ```
   .navbar
   — ul.navbar-nav
   — — li
   — — li
   ...
   — — li
   — — .navbar-nav:after
   ```

And this style (only non-standard for bootstrap styles are shown):

```
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: justify;
  > li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
.navbar-nav:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And it doesn't work! Can you help me?

Comment: There is nav-justified class built in Bootstrap 3. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

Answer (score 3):

You can try to replace `navbar-nav` with `nav-justified`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">
  <li><a href="/news">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a href="/video">Видео</a></li>
  <li><a href="/texts">Тексты</a></li>
  <li><a href="/photo">Фото</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">О группе</a></li>
  <li><a href="/music">Купить музыку</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://shop.staceydogs.ru/">Магазин</a></li>
</ul>
```

Example of Bootstrap's built-in `nav-justified` can be found in here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

OT: You seem to have unnecessary navbar -related classes in your elements. E.g.

```
<header class="nav navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
```

I suggest you will check the example's source code and fix your markup accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've deleted unnecessary classes from header and ul tag, but the problem is still here.

Some words about nav-justified: it does some another thing, no some I want. Let's see the behaviour on nav-justified: https://yadi.sk/i/vH8_jCeyXJjxJ all menu items have the same width, but spaces between them don't. And let's see the behaviour of 'text-align: justified': https://yadi.sk/i/fqtrMQUbXJkwN all spaces between menu items have the same width. That is what I want.